# How can I group by pre-grouped data and should it even be done?

Tags: c#, .net, group-by, grouping

I have records that are already grouped by an index value in a structure similar to this:

```
  Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> Data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>()
        {
                //Propety Name

            {   "JobPosition", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() 
                {
                    //Property Value              Records with that Value

                    { "Sales", new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_1", "Record_ID_2" } },
                    { "Engineer", new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_3", "Record_ID_4" } },
                    { "Manager", new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_5", } },
                }
            },
            {
                //Property Name

                "EmploymentClassification", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
                {
                    //Property Value                 Records with that value

                    { "Full_Time", new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_1", "Record_ID_2", "Record_ID_5" } },
                    { "Part_Time", new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_3", "Record_ID_4" } },
                }
            }
        };
```

Now a request comes in to group the records by Job Position & Employment Classification, which should produce something like the following results:

```
Dictionary<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, List<string>> final = new Dictionary<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, List<string>>()
        {
            {
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() //KEY
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobPosition", "Sales"), //Indicies[0][0]
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmploymentClassification", "Full_Time")//Indicies[1][0]
                },
                new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_1", "Record_ID_2" } //Value
            },
            {
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() //Key
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobPosition", "Engineer"), //Indicies[0][1]
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmploymentClassification", "Part_Time")//Indicies[1][1]
                },
                new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_3", "Record_ID_4" } //Value
            },
            {
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() //Key
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobPosition", "Manager"), //Indicies[0][2]
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmploymentClassification", "Full_Time")//Indicies[1][0]
                },
                new List<string>(){ "Record_ID_5" } //Value
            },
        };
```

I want to leverage my pre-grouped data to create these new groups in such a way that I do not need to iterate the full list of records. I'd rather iterate over the indices and consolidate on the intersection of records. However, I wonder if in doing the consolidation of records for a particular group, am I going to end up iterating over every record anyway, which in that case I might as well just iterate the records, creating the groups or adding to a group as I go, ignoring the indexed data altogether.

The other thing to note is that the property names and values of the actual indices at runtime are not hardcoded in this way, I will not know which properties or values we are looking at, so the solution needs to be generalized to work with any incoming index dictionary of any size.

## **Here's what I've Tried**

I've tried creating the group keys first, and then intersecting the results, but the performance was very poor.

I created a class to hold the group keys:

```
public class PropertyValueGroupKey
    {
        public List<Tuple<string, string>> Values { get; set; } = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj is PropertyValueGroupKey other)
            {
                if (other.Values.Count != this.Values.Count)
                    return false;
                return other.Values.All(x => this.Values.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Item1 == x.Item1 && y.Item2 == x.Item2) != null);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 0;
            foreach (var element in Values)
            {
                hash = hash ^ EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(element.Item1);
                hash = hash ^ EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(element.Item2);
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

```
var baseIndex = indicies.FirstOrDefualt();
 foreach(var entry in baseIndex.Value)
            {
                var groupKey = new PropertyValueGroupKey();
                groupKey.Values.Add(Tuple.Create(baseIndex.Key, entry.Key));
                foreach(var otherIndex in indicies)
                {
                    if (otherIndex.Key == baseIndex.Key)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        foreach(var otherEntry in otherIndex.Value)
                        {
                            groupKey.Values.Add(Tuple.Create(otherIndex.Key, otherEntry.Key));
                        }
                    }
                }
                var data = filteredRecords;
                foreach(var key in groupKey.Values)
                {
                    data = indicies[key.Item1][key.Item2].Values.Intersect(data);
                }
                final.Add(groupKey, data.ToList());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SelectMany` to generate all possible combinations of job positions and employment classifications. For each combination, create a new object with a key property that is a list of key-value pairs, and a value property that is the intersection of the IDs for that job position and classification.

Something like this, based on your first grouping.

```
var finalGrouping = Data["JobPosition"].SelectMany(j => Data["EmploymentClassification"].Select(c => new
            {
                Key = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobPosition", j.Key),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmploymentClassification", c.Key)
                },
                Value = j.Value.Intersect(c.Value).ToList()
            })).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Only issue is that the keys, (i.e. Job Position and Employment Classification) are not known at runtime. Also, the presence of only 2 property keys is arbitrary, there could be 10 or 20 potentially. So the solution would need to be more generalized